# Reset DHCP IPs to beginning of range

Tags: networking, dhcp

Kind of a silly question, but I'm just curious as to how you'd reset the DHCP range of your server back to the beginning of it's designation.  I've tried restarting the DHCP service, but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: try deleting the `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases` file. Do so with caution, perhaps after a re-boot and before any clients obtain a lease.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks.  I'll try that tomorrow morning before anyone gets here and I make their lives miserable.  ;-)

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcp.leases` file. A good time to do it would be just after a re-boot, before any clients obtain a lease.

The dhcpd server will try to re-use old leases as much as possible, and will use unused IP addresses from the pool before using even expired leases. The advantage is users will tend to get the same IP address, even if their computer is not on the network very often. The disadvantage is that the leases file can get a bit messy over time.