# How to configure dhcp to always assign from the lowest unused ip?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vmware, dhcp, dhclient

I had a problem with vms that lose their previous ip after system restart, so after some time it will go from x.x.x.128 to x.x.x.136 etc. Short of switching to static ip, I had to resort to resetting dhcp ip address pool: [Reset DHCP IPs to beginning of range](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610152/reset-dhcp-ips-to-beginning-of-range)

I also found a better workaround from https://serverfault.com/a/381137, which works by configuring dhclient (which Network Manager uses to manage dhcp by default) to request a specific address for a particular interface:

```
interface "eth0" {
    send dhcp-requested-address 192.168.1.222;
}
```

Now, we know for sure that the original address of x.x.x.128 is not used by any other machine, since the vm guest is the only machine on that virtual network (apart from the host machine). Even though an address change was triggered for the vm guest, can dhcp be configured to assign x.x.x.128 if it is still unused?

Comment: In this case, the requested DHCP server is a part of the virtualization program. Please tell us which one do you use.

Comment: @Melebius it is vmware

Comment: This is an XY problem - Ask a question about "vms that lose their previous ip after system restart". Changing a DHCP server to assign addresses sequentially is a source-level change. - Not the way to go for simply debugging a problem.

Comment: which dhcp server are you using? As far as my experience goes, isc-dhcp-server will always give the same clients the same IP address just so long as it is available when they request it.

Comment: @waltinator a dhcp server is supposed to assign unused addresses. The question is about whether this behavior can be configured. If you claim that this is a source-level change, please back it up with evidence.

Comment: @DougSmythies apparently it is a virtualized component (for the host to act as a dhcp server) with some configurable options, but not full-featured like actual server

Comment: Then my suggestion is that you use a full isc-dhcp-server and get your VM's to use it. My VM's are all on my main LAN (bridged) and all get their IP address from my main DHCP server, which resides on a different Ubuntu server (but it doesn't have to).

Comment: @DougSmythies in my case I had a physical host (not Ubuntu) and a virtualized Ubuntu guest. For some reason I just thought that Ubuntu was the dhcp server (when it really wasn't)

Comment: Is your network card configured to NAT or BRIDGE?? Also, why can't you assign IP statically again? Which is the whole point of static IPs?

Comment: @meccooll it is a virtual NAT. While I can assign a static IP, I prefer to retain the default DHCP configuration, as long as the assigned ip address is stable. It appears that having the client request a particular unused address, is one way of achieving that.

Comment: So in virtual NAT vmware is running a process for DHCP server. Usually on DHCP servers you can do a manual mapping or set timeout how long it holds the IP but not sure if any of that is available in VMware?? You never explained why static doesn't work when you want static IP? But requesting a particular address might work *MOST* of the time

Comment: @meccooll there are no other machines on this virtual network, so DHCP should be okay if the assigned address was not changing erratically. It is okay for different address to be assigned if the requested address is somehow unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Melebius, the dhcp server in my scenario is not actually in the Ubuntu instance (vm guest) - it was simply a virtualized component (or "part of the virtualization program") on the host machine, with some configurable options. Even if I could configure it, it would have been independent of Ubuntu.

Hence, the workaround using `dhcp-requested-address` with `dhclient` seems to be the best option in this situation, with minimal change to a default installation.